# FieldCompletionFunction consumes a lot of CPU in Graphics

Tags: graphics, inputfield

The output of this code consumes a lot of CPU.

```
 Graphics@Inset@InputField[1,FieldCompletionFunction->({"a","b"}&)]
```

I found this occurs when FieldCompletionFunction is inside Graphics or Inset.

My System is 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 11, 2018)

Comment: Please don't use [tag:bugs] until it is confirmed by WRI or others.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try to be careful of that from now on.

Comment: Wolfram Cutomer Support sent email to me that this bug was removed in 12.1